# bash elif does not work as I expected

Tags: bash

Here is my script:

```
age=119

if [[$age -gt 99 ]]; then
    age_3digits=$age
elif [[$age -gt 9]]; then
    age_3digits=0$age
else
    age_3digits=00$age
fi   

z_grid=${age_3digits}Ma.grd
echo $z_grip


output: 00119Ma.grd
```

how come?? I am new to bash, thanks so much

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Or just use: `printf -v age_3digits '%03d' "$age"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space after `[[` and before `]]`. Change to:

```
if [[ $age -gt 99 ]]; then
    age_3digits=$age
elif [[ $age -gt 9 ]]; then
    age_3digits=0$age
else
    age_3digits=00$age
fi
```

It's also better to use arithmetic expressions because it makes your code more readable, like this:

```
if (( age > 99 )); then
    age_3digits=$age
elif (( age > 9 )); then
    age_3digits=0$age
else
    age_3digits=00$age
fi
```